# Remove and release an type object from a view

Tags: ios

I have a class call Post and its a view....i add it some times in my main view like this:
take a lock how to remove and release this object from my self.view....
i just have this class:

```
@interface Post : UIView{
      UILabel * label1;
      UILabel * label2;
      UILabel * label3;
}
@implementation Post
-(void)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
         label1 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
         label2 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
         label3 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
         label1.frame = CGRect(10,10,100,30);
         label2.frame = CGRect(10,60,100,30);
         label3.frame = CGRect(10,110,100,30);

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

and this main class controller

```
@implementation HomeViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad{
     Post *p = [[Post alloc]init]
     p.frame = CGRect(0,0,0,320,460);
     p.backgroundColor = [UIColor blue];
     [self.view addsubview: p];
     [p release];


     Post *p2 = [[Post alloc]init]
     p2.frame = CGRect(0,0,0,320,460);
     p2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blue];
     [self.view addsubview:p2];
     [p2 release];

     Post *p3 = [[Post alloc]init]
     p3.frame = CGRect(0,0,0,320,460);
     p3.backgroundColor = [UIColor blue];
     [self.view addsubview:p3];
     [p3 release];

}
-(void)RemoveAllPosts
{
//How to remove and release all post from self.view???
}
@end
```

Comment: Do include `-(void)dealloc {
    [label1 release];
    [label2 release];
    [label3 release];
}` method in your `Post` class and Paramasivan has answered your question

Comment: ohhh ok!! if i release by my self before release my object post i didnt need to release in dealloc right? looks like that:[p.label1 release]; [p.label2 release]; [p.label3 release]; [p release];

Comment: you can do that weird coding but dealloc is best place to release you alloced object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below lines of code.

```
for(UIView *viewInner in self.view.subviews) {
    if([viewInner isKindOfClass:[Post class]])
        [viewInner removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: You already released it by adding release command after adding it to subview. So removing it from superview will be enough, i think.

Comment: ohh thats right i thinks is that! if i try to release it crashes